# Do I need Ionic secure storage plugin?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have an ionic 3 application. I'm using `localStorage`, developers say it's not reliable so I'm migrating to [ionic storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/), then I see [secure storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage/), the sensitive data in the application are the login token for Rest API and Facebook login token.

I find it hard to accept that I need two plugins for storage. Do I really need them both?

Comment: Tokens are sensitive but depending on your app and what it does it can be ok to store it in Ionic Storage. Use secure storage if risks of someone taking advantage of that data is really high, but keep in mind that secure storage on the client is also not the ultimate protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to both two plugin, please try to follow ionic storage for login token for Rest API [ionic storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/).

**Need to follow Configuring Storage**

The Storage engine can be configured both with specific storage engine priorities, or custom configuration options to pass to localForage. See the localForage config docs for possible options: https://github.com/localForage/localForage#configuration